# I was following a blog post to install postgresql and start getting this error while updating my OS

Tags: 14.04, apt, postgresql

```
N: Ignoring file 'pgdg.listsudo' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/'
  as it has an invalid filename extension
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is not an error, but a Notice (N:).

Filename extension should be `.list` instead of `.listsudo`. Probably you made a copy-paste mistake.

Fix:

```
sudo mv /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.listsudo /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list
```

--

That said, unless you explicitly need a newer version, you should probably install the `postgresql` package that is provided by Ubuntu instead of using third-party repositories.